# Download the Monent.js to the SharePoint server

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server

Could some on guide me as how to download the `Monent.js` to the SharePoint server?

I know that I can reference it, using

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> */
```

but how would I make it local?

Comment: can't I hear something from you? @joe222

Answer (score 0):

Go to the following link

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/locale/af.js

Press **Ctrl+S**

Save and move it to SharePoint server if your SharePoint server does not have internet connection.

If you have internet connection your SharePoint Server, then do it from there.

Now upload `moment.js` file into any asset library like `Site Assets`. So your reference should look like following

```
<script src="/Site Assets/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```